# How to fix a "could not find module" error in Cabal, when it seems correctly specified?

Tags: haskell, cabal

I'm currently not using stack at all on this project (just Cabal), and all was going well when everything was in Main.hs. I decided to split up code, moving my dhall dep and related code from my executable deps to my library deps, and now seem to have this strange error when running `cabal new-build`:

```
Building executable 'FarmDataServer.exe' for FarmDataServer-0.1.0.0..                                                                                                                                      
<no location info>: warning: [-Wmissing-home-modules]                                                                                 
    These modules are needed for compilation but not listed in your .cabal file's other-modules: FDS                                  
                                                                                                 FDS.Config.Core                      
                                                                                                 FDS.Config.DhallConf                 
[2 of 4] Compiling FDS.Config.DhallConf ( src/FDS/Config/DhallConf.hs, /home/brandon/workspace/CIDA/FarmDataServer/dist-newstyle/buil
d/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.4.4/FarmDataServer-0.1.0.0/x/FarmDataServer.exe/build/FarmDataServer.exe/FarmDataServer.exe-tmp/FDS/Config/Dhall
Conf.o )                                                                                                                              

src/FDS/Config/DhallConf.hs:7:1: error:                                                                                               
    Could not find module `Dhall'                                                                                                     
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.                                                                                   
  |                                                                                                                                   
7 | import           Dhall                                                                                                            
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Certainly I'm also a bit confused by the `Wmissing-home-modules` message since I seem to have added those in my cabal file.

Relevant bits of my .cabal file:

```
cabal-version:       2.4
name:                FarmDataServer
version:             0.1.0.0

library
  exposed-modules:
    FDS

  other-modules:
    FDS.Config.Core
    , FDS.Config.DhallConf

  build-depends:       base             ^>=4.11.1.0
                       , conduit        ^>=1.3.1
                       , csv-conduit    ^>=0.7.0.0
                       , dhall          ^>=1.20.0
                       , text           ^>=1.2.3.1

  hs-source-dirs:      src



executable FarmDataServer.exe
  main-is:             Main.hs

  build-depends:       base             ^>=4.11.1.0
                       , conduit        ^>=1.3.1
                       , csv-conduit    ^>=0.7.0.0
                       , scotty         ^>=0.11.3
                       , text           ^>=1.2.3.1
                       , FarmDataServer ^>=0.1.0.0
```

My `src` folder:

```
$ pwd                                                                                                                                 
/home/brandon/workspace/CIDA/FarmDataServer/src
$ du -a                                                                                                                               
4       ./FDS/Config/DhallConf.hs                                                                                                     
4       ./FDS/Config/Core.hs                                                                                                          
12      ./FDS/Config                                                                                                                  
16      ./FDS                                                                                                                         
4       ./FDS.hs                                                                                                                      
4       ./Main.hs                                                                                                                     
28      .
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the missing modules, sink your program executable into a directory such that the module hierarchy for yoru library isn't visible:

```
mkdir program ; mv src/Main.hs program/
```

and in cabal for the executable

```
hs-source-dirs: program
```

For your missing module `Dhall`, add the `dhall` build dependency to your `executable` stanza in the cabal file.